# Oracle Spatial operator SDO_ANYINTERACT does not work well

Tags: polygon, java, oracle-spatial

DB:

> Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production Version 19.3.0.0.0

I have a table called `GRID_POINT_BOUNDARY` and one column I am using `SDO_GEOMETRY` Oracle Spatial type. The table structure is the following and I indeed set up the index and `USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA` configuration.

```
CREATE TABLE "MINTAKA"."GRID_POINT_BOUNDARY"
      (
        "BOUNDARY_ID" NUMBER(19,0),
        "BOUNDARY_DEF" MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY NOT NULL ENABLE,
        CONSTRAINT "GRID_POINT_BOUNDARY_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("BOUNDARY_ID") ENABLE
     )

INSERT INTO USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA (TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DIMINFO, SRID)
VALUES ('GRID_POINT_BOUNDARY',
        'BOUNDARY_DEF',
        SDO_DIM_ARRAY( -- in our case, we only have 2 dimensions, latitude and longitude
                SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('Longitude', -180, 180, 0.0001),
                SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('Latitude',   -90,  90, 0.0001)
            ),
        4326 
       );

CREATE INDEX GRID_POINT_BOUNDARY_DEF_IDX ON MINTAKA.GRID_POINT_BOUNDARY (BOUNDARY_DEF) INDEXTYPE IS MDSYS.SPATIAL_INDEX
```

I created two boundary rows among the `GRID_POINT_BOUNDARY` table.
One boundary edge is parallel with the lon/lat line, its content is

```
MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2003, 4326, NULL, MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 1003, 1), MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(168, -44, 170, -44, 170, -42, 168, -42, 168, -44))
```

The other boundary edge is crossed with the lon/lat line, its content is

```
MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2003, 4326, NULL, MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 1003, 1), MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(168, -44, 170, -46, 172, -44, 170, -42, 168, -44))
```

**When I use `Spatial Operators - SDO_ANYINTERACT` function to check whether one point(lon/lat) is inside of the above boundary or not, I find the `SDO_ANYINTERACT` works not well if the point is a little up or down the edge of the boundary! Actually I tried other functions, but still no luck, eg: SDO_RELATE with nine patterns**

Eg: Point(169.0, -42.001) which is a little below the edge should be inside the following boundary(has the interaction) but the result is false

```
select 1 as result from dual where
MDSYS.SDO_ANYINTERACT( 
        MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2003, 4326, NULL, MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 1003, 1), MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(168, -44, 170, -44, 170, -42, 168, -42, 168, -44)),
        MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 4326, NULL, MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 1, 1), MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(169.0, -42.001))
        ) = 'TRUE';
```

but if I change the Point from (169.0, -42.001) into (169.0, -42.01), then the result becomes true. But 0.001(111.1 meters) and 0.01(1111.1 meters) of latitude has a huge difference in reality. Seems the line is not admitted as a straight line, but somehow a shape line.

```
select 1 as result from dual where
MDSYS.SDO_ANYINTERACT( 
        MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2003, 4326, NULL, MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 1003, 1), MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(168, -44, 170, -44, 170, -42, 168, -42, 168, -44)),
        MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 4326, NULL, MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 1, 1), MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(169.0, -42.01))
        ) = 'TRUE';
```

As a comparison, if choose a Point(169.0, -43.001) for the boundary which crosses the lon/lat line, it works well

```
select 1 as result from dual where
MDSYS.SDO_ANYINTERACT( 
        MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2003, NULL, NULL, MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 1003, 1), MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(168, -44, 170, -46, 172, -44, 170, -42, 168, -44)),
        MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, NULL, NULL, MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 1, 1), MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(169.0, -43.001))
        ) = 'TRUE';
```

As a wrap-up, the `SDO_ANYINTERACT` seems behaviour different during the polygon boundary edges are parallel or cross the lon/lat line? Did I miss something?

Comment: When you use a geographic coordinate system Oracle Spatial will take in account the curvature of the earth, so a rectangle in coordinates isn't really a rectangle anymore but will get curved sides. This results in differences when working with points close to the edges. If you would use NULL or a projected srs instead of 4326 you won't have this effect.

Comment: @Pieter By setting it NULL, would it just use a simple projection where lat lines are horizontal and longitude vertical, therefore all intersection algorithms are compatible with shapes drawn using Web Mercator?

Comment: @Craig Yes, if srid is NULL the coordinates are treated as simple cartesian ones.